# A simple question about conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, conditional-probability

Let $(X_n)_{n \ge 0}$ be a homogeneous Markov chain with a countable state space $(E,\mathcal B).$

Why we have that $$\mathbf{P} \left ( X_r=i,X_{r-1} \ne j,...,X_1\ne j\mid X_0={i}\right )\cdot\mathbf{P} \left ( X_n=j,X_{n-1} \ne \left\{i,j \right\},...,X_{r+1}\ne \left\{i,j \right\}\mid X_r={i}\right )=$$
$$\mathbf{P} \left ( X_n=j,X_{n-1} \ne \left\{i,j \right\},...,X_{r+1}\ne \left\{i,j \right\},X_r=i,X_{r-1} \ne j,...,X_1\ne j\mid X_0={i}\right )$$

Answer (score 1):

All $\{X_{k}\}_{k=r+1}^n$ are independent of all $\{ X_{p} \}_{p=0}^{r-1}$ given $X_{r}$, by the Markov property. Therefore
\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{P} \left ( X_n=j,X_{n-1} \ne \left\{i,j \right\},...,X_{r+1}\ne \left\{i,j \right\}\mid X_r={i}\right )\\
={}&\mathbf{P} \left ( X_n=j,X_{n-1} \ne \left\{i,j \right\},...,X_{r+1}\ne \left\{i,j \right\}\mid X_r={i},X_r=i,X_{r-1} \ne j,...,X_1\ne j, X_0={i} \right )
\end{align*}

Comment: Get straight to the point !

Comment: I believe that from my hint, you should have enough information to understand what is going on. A good reason not to give a better explanation is that it will force you to engage with the subject more actively and therefore you will get the best of the learning experience. Of course you can ask me specific question about what you don't understand. If this doesn't suit you, you probably want to ask your question on another forum.